# How to say "go by bike"

Tags: english-to-japanese

I want to say "many Dutch (go by | take the | use the ) bike". (or car,...)

I've come up with:

> おおぜいのオランダ人は自転車{じてんしゃ}で行{い}きます。

and

> おおぜいのオランダ人｛じん｝は自転車{じてんしゃ}を使{つか}います。

But they seem very constructed to me and I'm not sure whether you can omit the thing for which they use a bike. But I want to omit that!

How can I say this properly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe it will more sound natural if the sentence goes like this.

多くのオランダ人は自転車に乗ります。

This way it can mean "to use"  "go by" or " take the" , which you want to tell.

Comment: This is the correct short answer.  To use 「行きます」 as OP did, there needs to exist beforehand a mutual understnding between the speaker and listener (or writer and reader) as to exactly where the Dutch are going.

Comment: Or more natural construction may be オランダでは自転車に乗る人が多いです, though this is stating about the Netherlands, not Dutch people.

Answer (score 1):

Both ”大勢のオランダ人は自転車で行きます” and ”大勢のオランダ人は自転車で行きます" are right as the direct translation of “Many Dutch (go by | take the | use the ) bike". (or car,...), but sound somewhat stiff or unrefined to me as a Japanese expression.
Just as a suggestion, how about saying, just by changing the angle of construction:

オランダでは自転車に乗っている人を多く見かけます – In Netherlands, we see a lot of people riding (using) a bicycle.

オランダでは多くの人が日常 （or ふだん）自転車を使用しています – In Netherlands many people make daily use of bicycles.